# Leaderboard in Unity3d(C#,PHP)

Tags: php

Hi guys i'm having a problem in my php script and it says

> Notice: Undefined index: Name in
>   /storage/h6/881/1096881/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Score in
>   /storage/h6/881/1096881/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: hash in
>   /storage/h6/881/1096881/public_html/InsertScore.php on line 17

```
try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $hostname .';dbname='. $database,   $username, $password);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<h1>An error has ocurred.</h1><pre>', $e->getMessage() ,'</pre>';
    }

    $realHash = md5($_GET['Name'] . $_GET['Score'] . $secretKey); 
    if($realHash == $hash) { 
        $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO getdataofplayer VALUES (null, :Name, :Score)');
        try {
            $sth->execute($_GET);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo '<h1>An error has ocurred.</h1><pre>', $e->getMessage() ,'</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: The answer is in your problem. Notice: **Undefined** index. And [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/7431119)

Comment: @Condorcho just following the tuts here http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores

Comment: `// Strings must be escaped to prevent SQL injection attack. 
        $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'], $db); 
        $score = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['score'], $db); 
        $hash = $_GET['hash'];` You missed that part.

Comment: i use PDO query sir

Comment: Yes, misread. You just need to define the variables that are undefined. `$name = $_GET['name']`, etc. Remember to sanitize before inserting.

Comment: @Condorcho i already tried that but still it keeps giving me an undefined index error

Comment: What's line 16? I'm assuming it's `$realHash = ....`. If so, make sure you're passing `Name` and `Score` in the URL.

Comment: @Condorcho what do you mean passing **Name** and **Score** in the URL? i don't get it sorry

Comment: You should have something like `addscore.php?Name=SOMETHING&Score=SOMETHING`

Comment: http://jresoor12345.000webhostapp.com/InsertScore.php?Name=John%20Doe&Score=100&hash=mySecretKey. it doesn't add on my database sir